# Equal power filterbank

Tags: filter-bank

Is there a specific algorithm/formula for computing the bandwidths of filter banks across a frequency range where each bank has equal power/volume/intensity?  (The bandwidths will be different for each band, but should still all sum up to the total bandwidth).

(For example, a section split into 5 bands across 2kHz to 5kHz. At a given instant, the algorithm determines that each band needs to be 2dB, with the first band having a bandwidth of 200Hz (ranging from 2kHz to 2.2kHz), the second band having a bandwidth of 400Hz, the third band having a bandwidth of 700kHz, the fourth band having a bandwidth of 700Hz, and the fifth band having a bandwidth of 1000Hz)

My current plan of attack on this problem is something like number partitioning over a DFT vector, but I could be dead wrong.

I'm aware that the bandwidth will shift as volume/intensity changes, and I'm also aware intensity is loosely defined in this scenario, so I'm guessing some kind of envelope follower will be needed.

Comment: multi-band audio compressor?

Comment: the power from a single filter in a filterbank depends on the power of the input over the bandwidth of that filter.  so some assumption has to be made about the nature of the input signal to the filterbank.

Comment: ...also, if you try to do this in an "adaptive" way, you are going to have to put in a lot of work with interpolation and slow bandwidth updates to keep the adaptation from being audible. What is the purpose for this?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson not a multi-band audio compressor, as that would be modifying the volume after the fact. I want the volume to be calculated ONLY by setting the bandwidth.

Comment: @A_A i'm simply trying this out for a musical project and I'm curious as to how it will turn out, but I'm unsure how to implement it and can't find anything like it.

Comment: well, then i don't understand what you wanna do.